# How to create a graph with sugraph with jgrapht

Tags: jgrapht

I want to create a graph with subgraphs (I think cluster is a synonymous - not sure ?). Someone could explain how to create this type of graph and how to export this composite graph. I readed this post [Creating graph with clusters using jgrapht](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820898/creating-graph-with-clusters-using-jgrapht/57837344#57837344) but i am not sure to understand this sentence "You could create a graph where each vertex is a graph by itself; **edges between these vertices represent relations between these special vertices**.". Does it mean that in this case verticles are relations between subgraphs. How to build this verticles? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In JGraphT, vertices and edges are arbitrary objects: a `Graph<V,E>` consists of vertices of type `V`, and edges of type `E`. See the wiki guide https://jgrapht.org/guide/UserOverview for details.

So you could simply define a graph where `V` is also a graph: `Graph<Graph<String,DefaultEdge>,DefaultEdge>`. In this example, each vertex in the graph, is a graph by itself, consisting of String vertices and DefaultEdge edges.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this graph composed from subgraph (verticles/nodes) and in which each subgraph is composed by nodes and edges. What is the composition of the relationships between the subgraph?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question, "what is the composition of relationships between the subgraph"? It would probably also help if you specified your use-case, since a graph in which the vertices are also graphs, are highly uncommon and only used in very specific applications