# how to create a subgraph with jgrapht

Tags: java, jgrapht, subgraph

I am using `jgrapht` in `Java` to work a network-based algorithm. I first read an adjacency list and then create `jgrapht` based graph. Now, given a subset of nodes called `subNodes`, I'd like to generate a sub graph. I am trying to use `Subgraph` class as shown at [this link](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-1.1.0/org/jgrapht/graph/Subgraph.html), however, I could not have it worked.

```
import org.jgrapht.*;
import org.jgrapht.graph.*;
......

HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> adjacencyList = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();
\\fill out adjacency list

\\create your graph
Graph<Integer, DefaultEdge> myGraph =  new SimpleGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
 
int numNodes = ...;
for(int i = 0 ; i <numNodes; i++) 
  myGraph.addVertex(i);
    

for(int i = 0 ; i< numNodes; i++) { 
    if(adjacencyList.get(i) != null) {
        for(Integer j : adjacencyList.get(i)) {
            myGraph.addEdge(i, j);
        }
    }
}
Set<Integer> subNodes = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
\\generate a sub set of vertices to have a subgprah
```

A similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805890/how-to-create-a-graph-with-sugraph-with-jgrapht), but that also did not help.

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are referring to some old javadoc. Not sure why you are specifically using the 1.1.0. Here's an example using the 1.5 version of jgrapht:

```
public class SubGraphExample {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Graph<Integer, DefaultEdge> g = new SimpleGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
        Graphs.addAllVertices(g, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
        g.addEdge(1,2);
        g.addEdge(2,3);
        g.addEdge(3,4);
        g.addEdge(4,1);
        System.out.println("Graph: "+g);

        //Subgraph
        Set<Integer> vertexSubset = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2));
        Graph<Integer, DefaultEdge> subgraph = new AsSubgraph<>(g, vertexSubset);
        System.out.println("Subgraph: "+subgraph);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Graph: ([1, 2, 3, 4], [{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,1}])
Subgraph: ([1, 2], [{1,2}])
```

You should always have a look at the examples included in the test directories. The `AsSubgraph` class comes with the `AsSubgraphTest` class which can be found in the [test suite](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/test/java/org/jgrapht/graph/AsSubgraphTest.java).
The latest javadoc (1.5.0 at the time of writing) can be found here: https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/